# How can access google analytics data in cron job without login?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I want to access google analytics page views and store them in database using a cron job. How can i access google analytics without login.

Besically i am accessing google account in cron job. so i have no idea how to access it google apps offline.

Plz plz anyone help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming its your own data and not someone elses you can use a service account

Comment: but where to access service account to access ?? i have no idea what it is... And yes it my own data. @DaImTo

Comment: @DaImTo I got service account.. but no idea how to use it.. can explain ?

Answer (score 2):

A service account will allow your application to access your Google Analytics data without prompting a user for access.

**Granting Access**

A service account doesn’t need to prompt a user for access because you have to set it up. Go to the Google Analytics website in the Admin section for the Account you want to retrieve data from. This is very important it must be at the account level add this email address as a new user. just give them read access.

[image]

**code**

```
<?php
   require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
   session_start();     
/************************************************   
 The following 3 values an befound in the setting   
 for the application you created on Google      
 Developers console.         Developers console.
 The Key file should be placed in a location     
 that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
 web root.       web root.

 In order to access your GA account you must    
 Add the Email address as a user at the     
 ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.         
 ************************************************/
    $client_id = '[Your client id]';
    $Email_address = '[YOur Service account email address Address]';     
    $key_file_location = '[Locatkon of key file]';      

    $client = new Google_Client();      
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    

    // seproate additional scopes with a comma   
    $scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($Email_address,         
                             array($scopes),        
                             $key);     

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
         $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);      
    }       

    $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);



    //Adding Dimensions
    $params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType'); 
    // requesting the data  
    $data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:89798036", "2014-12-14", "2014-12-14", "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );     
?>

<html>   
Results for date:  2014-12-14<br>
    <table border="1">   
        <tr>     
        <?php    
        //Printing column headers
        foreach($data->getColumnHeaders() as $header){
             print "<td><b>".$header['name']."</b></td>";       
            }       
        ?>      
        </tr>       
        <?php       
        //printing each row.
        foreach ($data->getRows() as $row) {        
            print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";   
        }    
?>      
<tr><td colspan="2">Rows Returned <?php print $data->getTotalResults();?> </td></tr>     
</table>     
</html>
```

Code ripped from [Google Analytics Service account](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/) tutorial

Comment: I tried all this and then it says I have wrong JSON, so after some stackoverflowing I found that I need another JSON for which I have to have GSuite in order to create OAuth... So now I am confused.

Comment: you dont need gsuite to access google analytics data.   you probably created the wrong credentials type

Comment: How can I create right type of JSON? I tried a lot of ways, but seems I don't get it right. And I couldn' t find answer. What type of JSON do I need and how to create it?

Comment: Im not exactly sure what you mean by the right type of json.  Go to google developer console create a service account.  Download the json key file.

Comment: I did that and then when I try to access data I get this error Uncaught Google_Exception: Invalid client secret JSON file.

Comment: This code of yours, that you ripped from google analytics service account, it requires JSON on line $key_file_location = '[Locatkon of key file]'; When I include JSON I downloaded, and when try to test the code in browser I got the error Invalid client secret JSON file.

Comment: Ok I get it... I fixed the error above, where do I acquire $client_id from?

Comment: Ok I resolved everything, my client id, I needed .p12 file not JSON, get it all. Thank you. Can I get real time data with this code?

Comment: you dont need the .p12 file you need the json file you shouldnt be using the .p12 file

Comment: Yes I do, check the comments on your link. I did everything I needed with this tutorial of yours, thank you. You' ve helped me big time.

Comment: this anwser is five years old you shouldnt need a p12 file.