# Is it possible to get number of current visits for link from GA?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I have a dashboard, CMS, and customer wants to see current number of views for dozen of links. So, I was wondering if I can get that from Google Analytics. I send request with links, GA returns only number and every user must see these numbers, even though they are not admins on GA for this very page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/ is what you need

Comment: Yeah, I know about this, but when I embed it, it asks me first to login. My client has arount 30 employees and none of them has access to full analytics. He just wants them to see current number of visitors and some other links.

Comment: @Korovjov thats what service account authentication is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you will have is that Google Analytics data is private user data. There for in order to see this data you must first login or be authenticated in some way.  For what you are thinking of doing you should consider using a service account.

Think of a service account as a dummy user, it has its own google drive account google calendar account and also google analytics account.   The great thing with service accounts is that they can be pre authorized to grant them access to data.   By taking the service account email address and adding it as a user in the Google analytics admin section it will have access to that data without needing to be logged in.

Another thing you will need to consider is quota you can make max 10k requests a data against a single view with your application, this can not be increased so i recommend you cache this data somehow.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I think I would make my own analytics than. :D

Comment: You can do it with GA dont get me wrong but quota makes it difficult.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone having same/similar issue:

1. Check this link : [How can access google analytics data in cron job without login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452417/how-can-access-google-analytics-data-in-cron-job-without-login/31453248?noredirect=1)
2. Create .p12 file connected to service account you' ve created in a process
3. You change params so you can get Real Time

You can check my code for reference (this was only testing code):

```
 require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
   session_start();
/************************************************
 The following 3 values an befound in the setting
 for the application you created on Google
 Developers console.         Developers console.
 The Key file should be placed in a location
 that is not accessable from the web. outside of
 web root.       web root.

 In order to access your GA account you must
 Add the Email address as a user at the
 ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.
 ************************************************/
    $client_id = '[your_service_account_id]';
    $Email_address = '[your_service_email_account]';
    $key_file_location = '[.p12_file_location]'
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

    // seproate additional scopes with a comma
    $scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($Email_address,
                             array($scopes),
                             $key);

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
         $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }

    $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);



    //Adding Dimensions
    $params = array('dimensions' => 'rt:medium');
    // requesting the data
    $results = $service->data_realtime->get(
      'ga:[your_view_id]',
      'rt:activeUsers',
      $params);
?>

<html>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <?php
        //Printing column headers
        foreach($results->getColumnHeaders() as $header){
             print "<td><b>".$header['name']."</b></td>";
            }
        ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
        //printing each row.
        foreach ($results->getRows() as $row) {
            print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";
        }

        $totals = $results->getTotalsForAllResults();

        $html='';
        foreach ($totals as $metricName => $metricTotal) {
            $html .= "Metric Name  = $metricName\n";
            $html .= "Metric Total = $metricTotal";
        }

?>
<tr><td colspan="2">Rows Returned <?php print $results->getTotalResults();?> </td></tr>
</table>

<?php print $html; ?>
</html>
```